# Getting the Average for one Person with many values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there is a column with people's names (PersonNames). Their names appear more than once, but each time with a different integer in another column(Scores). I am trying to get the average score for each person, but I don't want to manually do it for each person. What queries can I use?

Comment: ,Provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the average score of each person as below.

```
select name,avg(scores)
from [YourTable]
group by name
```